# Do I need to call next() if an error in a callback is present?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Let's say I have a `mongoose` call to retrieve some documents from the database. I have two cases:

1. If I want any specific behavior in the `callback` function executed after the database call returns, e.g.

   ```
   function(err, model) {
       if(err){
           do some specific behavior in this case
           ???
       }
       ...do something with the model.
   })
   ```

   In this case do I call `next(err)` at the `???` or I simply do nothing and the error will propagate up to the middleware to be handled?
2. If I do not want any specific behavior in the `callback` function executed after the database call returns, e.g.

   ```
   function(err, model) {
       ...do something with the model.
   })
   ```

   So if an error occurred I just want my middleware to handle it. Do I need to call `if (err) next(err)` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always check for errors. Let's say your db is down. In your second case, you will try to do something with the model without testing for err. And there is no model, since the db is down, and your whole app crashes.

As for calling next, this depends on where your mongoose call is. If it is an express/connect middleware, there you do have to call it, something like next(err) or next(null, result), depending if you have an error or not.

If you're doing it inside a route handler (with req and res), again you need to res.end() in case of an error or the request remains handling.

The best case is if you have this call in a module.  So in that module you're exporting a function that will do this db call. If that function is designed with a callback, and if you're following the usual (err, result) pattern, then you should check for callback and call it if exists.

Comment: I thought when an error is thrown the rest of the code after that is not executed. So the parameter in the callback is not a thrown error, just an `Error` object returned by the database?

Comment: I want the to handle the errors in a middleware, where I log the error and simply return an error page similar to what `express'` default error handler does.

Comment: No, if your call has an error, and you later try to execute something with that non-existant object, your app will crash - since you did not handle that error. The middleware will redirect to error page if there are problems - that is why you can either call next() with error as the first argument. Then express/connect know you had an error in the middleware and they can show that error page.